# "Can't resolve '..node_modules/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot' "and other font awesome files

Tags: angular, sass, angular-cli

I have been cracking my head for a solution to this issue. Can someone please help?

Problem: I wanted to use font awesome in my application and I installed it through Angular-CLI

and included this in styles.scss

$fa-font-path: "../node_modules/font-awesome/fonts";
@import "../node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome";

webpack version: 4.44.2

error:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you installed font awesome with cli to project, You dont need to put it inside styles.scss jsut put inside angular.json styles attributes

```
 "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
```

or you can use it with adding [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-58rdec?file=src/app/app.component.html)

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

inside index.html without using library

Comment: Hey thanks for this!
I tried both your suggestions, although yeah the second one worked fine. The first one didnt work.. there are no build errors but the icons are not being displayed. And i want to use the library.

Comment: Which icons do you want ?